# SSL Certificate non-www not working

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4

If I am going to type https://www.example.com the site is working. If I am going to type https://example.com the site is not working. The certificate should support example.com and also www.example.com. I do have have European-SSL Certifcate (cheapest one).

Short:

```
https://www.example.com --> working
https://example.com --> not working
```

What is wrong with the apache2.4.7 config?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain/live/web"

ServerAdmin hostmaster@example.de
ServerName www.example.de
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory "/var/www/domain/live/web">
     Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>

            DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/live/web"
            ServerAdmin hostmaster@example.com
            ServerName www.example.com
            ServerAlias example.com
            DirectoryIndex app.php

            <Directory "/var/www/domain/live/web">
                    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
            CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/example.com.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/example.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/example.com.ca
            SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
            SSLHonorCipherOrder On
            SSLCompression off
   </VirtualHost>
```

PS: I am using symfony2.7 - but I guess it does not matter.

Comment: You need one certificate for domain and another one for subdomain, else it is a Wildcard certificate and it cas be applied to both. Is it a Wilcard SSL certificate ?

Comment: We are unlikely to be able to help without seeing the certificate.

Comment: When you say certificate is not working, that mean site is working but warn with a message that Certificat isn't valid ? Any log in Apache ?

Comment: Oh, okay, misspelled, of course the site, not certifcate. I do have an post on Anthony's answer. So the SSL-Certifcate should work for www and non-www https. Am I right?

Comment: As Froggiz suggested, you should also edit your answer to include relevant entries in the relevant Apache error log. You should also include details of the error reported by the browser when attempting to access `http://www.domain.com`. I presume `www.domain.com` resolves to the correct IP address.

Comment: "The site is not working" is not a helpful problem description. What *precisely* goes wrong?

Comment: Typo: the URL in my comment above should obviously be `https://domain.com` and the hostname should be `domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re not using a wildcard certificate, your certificate should include both names in the **Subject Alternative Name** field. If you’re using OpenSSL, this can be verified by running:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/domain.com.crt -noout -text |
     grep -A1 "Subject Alternative"
```

This should print output similar to:

```
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:domain.com, DNS:www.domain.com
```

If your SSL/TLS software doesn’t support the Subject Alternative Name extension (most modern software should do), the only name the certificate would be valid for is the *Common Name (CN)* specified in the certificate’s `Subject` field. This can be seen by running:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/domain.com.crt -noout -text | grep Subject:
```

If the certificate **is** a wildcard certificate, this would show output similar to:

```
    Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=*.domain.com
```

Comment: If this answer doesn't help, the question should be edited to include the information printed by the two OpenSSL commands.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I get exactly DNS:domain.com, DNS:www.domain.com, so https\:\/\/domain.com should work. Am I right? But it doesnot work.

Comment: @craphunter That's what you should see, alright.

Answer (score 0):

As @Froggiz has mentioned your SSL cert is probbaly only valid for one of the URIs

Assuming your SSL certificate is only for the www subdomain then you are probably best off using Apache to rewrite requests for the non www TLD to the www subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)
RewriteRule ^(.)*$ https://www.%1/$1 [R,L]
```

Although this doesn't answer your question exactly, it does provide a workaround which removes the problem

Comment: This doesn't work as for redirecting from non-www to www, you need ssl for both.